# ngAfterContentInit and ngAfterViewInit, which one occurs first

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular, just a question on ngAfterContentInit and ngAfterViewInit. Let's say we have the code below:

```
// this is comA's template.html
<table dirA>
  ...
  <td>...</td>
</table>
```

dirA applies on table element and there is a also a directive called `dirB` which applies to td element as:

```
@Directive({
   selector: "td"
})
export class dirB {
 ...
}
```

so inside comA class:

```
//pseudo code similarity
import dirB

@Component(...)   
export class comA {
  ...
  @ViewChildren(dirB)
  comAViewChildren: QueryList<dirB>;
}
```

and for dirA class:

```
import dirB

@Director(...)  //selector table 
export class dirA{
  ...
 @ContentChildren(dirB)
 dirAContentChildren: QueryList<dirB>;
}
```

So when the first time the page renderes, for ngAfterContentInit and ngAfterViewInit, which one occurs first? I could have setup everything and try, but even though I did that, I'm still confused with why is that, so it is better for me to ask the answer with reason first.to me, both of those should occurs simultaneously.

Comment: Try console logging inside both functions, then seeing which prints first.

Comment: @cs95 as I mentioned in the post I could have tested by myself, but I need to know the reason first

Comment: Why does one execute before the other? Because one is initialized before the other, or were you looking for a little more philosophy in the discussion? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Putting all theories aside, this is how its supposed to happen:

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence

1. AfterContentInit is first
2. AfterViewInit is next